# Haskell Fold implementation of `elemIndex`

Tags: function, haskell, fold

I am looking at Haskell `elemIndex` function:

```
elemIndex :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Maybe Int
```

What does `Maybe` mean in this definition? Sometimes when I call it, the output has a `Just` or a `Nothing` What does it mean? How can I interpret this if I were to use folds?

Comment: Did you check the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:elemIndex)? If the element occurs in the list, you get a `Just` value (holding the index of its first occurence), if it doesn't you get `Nothing`.

Comment: or if your comment was based on being unfamiliar with `Maybe` at all, see [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html) - or any of countless other good explanations online.

Comment: well.. I want to know how can I implement this with fold but I am not sure how to even try it because I don't know how to do the edge cases since there is a `Maybe`

Answer (score 1):

First question:

> What does it mean?

This means that the returned value is either an index (Int) or Nothing.

from the [docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:elemIndex):

> The **elemIndex** function returns the index of the first element in the given list which is equal (by ==) to the query element, or **Nothing** if there is no such element.

The second question:

> How can I interpret this if I were to use folds?

I'm not sure there is enough context to the "were to use folds" part. But, there are at least 2 ways to use this function:

1. case analysis, were you state what to return in each case:

```hs
case elemIndex xs of                                                                                           
  Just x -> f x        -- apply function f to x.
  Nothing -> undefined -- do something here, e.g. give a default value.
```

2. use function [maybe](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:maybe):

```hs
maybe defaultValue f (elemIndex xs)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Maybe` is a sum type.
Sum type is any type that has multiple possible representations.
For example:

`data Bool = False | True`

`Bool` can represented as `True` or `False`. The same goes with Maybe.

`data  Maybe a = Nothing | Just a`

> The Maybe type encapsulates an optional value. 
> A value of type Maybe a either contains a value of type a (represented as Just a), or it is empty (represented as Nothing)

`elemIndex :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Maybe Int`

> The elemIndex function returns the index of the first element in the given list which is equal (by ==) to the query element, or Nothing if there is no such element.

Lets compare it to the `indexOf` function
What are the possible values of this method?

1. The index of the element in the array in case it was found (lets say 2).
2. -1 in case it was not found.

Another way to represent it:

1. Return a number in case it was found - `Just 2`.
2. Instead of returning magic numbers like -1 we can return a value that represents the
   option of a failure - `Nothing`.

Regarding "How can I interpret this if I were to use folds", I do not have enough information to understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

`Maybe` is a type constructor.

`Int` is a type. `Maybe Int` is a type.

`String` is a type. `Maybe String` is a type.

For any type `a`, `Maybe a` is a type. Its values come in two varieties: either `Nothing` or `Just x` where `x` is a value of type `a` (we write: `x :: a`):

```
       x :: a
  -----------------                ------------------
  Just x :: Maybe a                Nothing :: Maybe a
```

In the first rule, the `a` in both the type of the value `x :: a` and the type of the value `Just x :: Maybe a` is the same. Thus if we know the type of `x` we know the type of `Just x`; and vice versa.

In the second rule, nothing in the value `Nothing` itself determines the `a` in its type. The determination will be made according to how that value is *used*, i.e. from the context of its usage, from its call site.

As to the fold implementation of `elemIndex`, it could be for example

```
elemIndex_asFold :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Maybe Int
elemIndex_asFold x0 = foldr g Nothing 
    where
    g x r | x == x0 = Just x
          | else    = r
```